# How do you import a custom module defined in another file?

Tags: elixir

a.exs:

```
defmodule A do
  def greet, do: IO.puts "hello"
end
```

b.exs:

```
defmodule B do
  import A
  def say_hello, do: greet
end
```

Result:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex b.exs
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

** (CompileError) b.exs:2: module A is not loaded and could not be found
```

---

```
~/elixir_programs$ tree .
.
├── a.exs
├── app1.exs
├── b.exs
....
```

For that matter, how do you use the qualified name to call a function defined in another module:

b.exs:

```
defmodule B do
  def say_hello, do: A.greet
end
```

---

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex b.exs
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> B.say_hello
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function A.greet/0 is undefined (module A is not available)
    A.greet()
```

Okay, this works:

```
iex(1)> c "a.exs"
[A]

iex(2)> B.say_hello
hello
:ok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> c "a.exs"
[A]

iex(2)> c "b.exs"
[B]

iex(3)> B.say_hello
hello
:ok

iex(4)>
```

Answer (score 21):

There are two main things one should understand about Elixir: it is *a compiled* language and it differentiates between *compiled files* and *scripts* (the latter are also compiled, but they do not compile automatically by `mix` by default.)

Compiled languages, unlike scripting languages (ruby, python, javascript, ...) are supposed to pass two stages before the functionality becomes available: the files should be compiled and *then* the runtime (read: Erlang VM) should be loaded. One cannot just `require 'foo'` as we do in ruby or `import bar` as we do in python and expect the thing to work.

Elixir provides handy helpers to do a compilation in runtime in [`Code`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html) module, including but not limited to: [`Code.require_file/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html#require_file/2) and [`Code.compile_file/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html#compile_file/2).

When using `mix`, only the *non-script* files, having an extension `.ex`, are compiled by default. That is why test files, being scripts (`.exs`) do not ever mess up with the runtime.

That said, there are four main options to make it work:

1. Use `mix` project and files named `a.ex` and `b.ex`. That way you’ll get everything on hand, compiled, by running `iex -S mix`.
2. Use `Code.require_file("a.exs")` from your `b.exs` to explicitly require `a.exs`.
3. Tell `iex` to compile (if necessary) and load all the files by running `iex -r a.exs -r b.exs`.
4. Do the compilation manually as you do in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If all the `.exs` files are in the same directory, you can run `iex -r *.exs` and that will load all the `.exs` into your iex session. You could also load the files one by one via `iex -r a.exs -r b.exs`

Answer (score 2):

You could use elixrc in your terminal (make sure both files are within the same folder), like so:

```
elixirc a.exs b.exs
```

This will generate `.beam` files. Those are bytecode files that erlang VM will run.